# Execution failed for task ':flutter_twitter_login:verifyReleaseResources

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I face this problem. Please help me.
Note:

```
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_facebook_login-3.0.0\android\src\main\java\com\roughike\facebooklogin\facebooklogin\FacebookLoginPlugin.java uses or o
verrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_twitter_login-1.1.0\android\src\main\java\com\roughike\fluttertwitterlogin\fluttertwitterlogin\TwitterLoginPlugin.java
 uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_sign_in-5.0.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlesignin\GoogleSignInPlugin.java uses or overrides a depreca
ted API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\libphonenumber-2.0.1\android\src\main\java\com\codeheadlabs\libphonenumber\LibphonenumberPlugin.java uses or overrides a depre
cated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 833KB to 826KB: Removed 0%

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_twitter_login:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\mehed\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b608c3d8537f54a7ed8ad86b3bfe3664\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVaria
tionSettings not found.

     C:\Users\mehed\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b608c3d8537f54a7ed8ad86b3bfe3664\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex
not found.
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12m 40s